# Adding page ID as a class to menu items in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to add the Page ID (not the menu item ID) of the menu item as a class to the menu element and I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Comment: [This question has been answered here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237793/add-page-id-class-to-nav-menu-items) [And here.]{https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237793/add-page-id-class-to-nav-menu-items/237795)